# For UI/UX interactions, should a drop down list be ordered by "best" or by numerical text?

Tags: user-interface, user-experience

Let's say you have a drop down and the values are "Strongest, weak, weakest."

You would put Strongest at the top of the drop down, and weakest at the bottom, yeah? When you see the drop down, the first option would be Strongest, last option would be Weakest.

Assuming that's true. If your options were from 0 to 20 but 20 was the best, and 0 was the worst. Shouldn't the drop down start with the best? In this case, it'd go from 20 to 0 with 20 at the top?

Comment: This is highly subjective. I'm not sure this is a great UX forum. In terms of coding, I can suggest that if a user can type a few characters and quickly select the answer that way, they have the best of both worlds - being able to type a number or item description quickly. But I don't see here whether it's on Mobile or Desktop, Web or App, whether it needs Accessibility considerations and more. So best find or start a UX forum.

Comment: Sigh. Good point. Not the easiest thing to Google for too. ;)

Comment: It depends on your User. You should be able to make a decision based on your own judgement and then you can always iterate/change in the future after feedback. Don't strain over such small details.